# How to validate an array of string with an enum in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of strings, that can only contain 6 kind of values. I've written this validation in my Mongoose schema:

```js
skills: [
      { type: String, enum: ["marketing", "sales", "tech", "hr", "management", "finance"] },
    ]
```

When creating an user with the key `skills: ["sales", "hr"]`, mongoose crashes, claiming that:

> Error: UserDB validation failed: skills.0: `["sales", "hr"]` is not a valid enum value for path `skills.0`.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a issue already fixed in mongoose [issues-6102](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6102), and provided a solution [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6102#issuecomment-365070314),

```
skills: {
  type: [
    { 
      type: String, 
      enum: ["marketing", "sales", "tech", "hr", "management", "finance"] 
    }
  ]
}
```